# What arguments to pass to inliner.parse() inside a custom role

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I am defining my custom role that allows :ref: markups to be inside of it. The role is to be used as follows:

```
myrole:`some_text |SUBS| more_text`
```

A function replaces |SUBS| by

```
:ref:`some_target`
```

so I end up with the following string

```
some_text :ref:`some_target` more_text
```

My python code is below in which I am not sure what to set the lineno, memo and parent argument to the inliner.parse() function

```
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive
from sphinx import addnodes

def myrole(role, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):

    app=inliner.document.settings.env.app
    #the below function replaces |SUBS| with the :ref: markup

    new_string=process_subs(text)
    
    nodelist,_=inliner.parse(new_string,lineno,memo,parent)

    return nodelist, []

    
def setup(app):
    app.add_role('myrole', myrole)
```

Comment: You need to explain what the problem is (edit the question). Please read [mcve]. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, still learning here!

Comment: updated the question to be simpler and clearer